# Python Atbash cypher

Tags: python, cypher

I'm trying to achieve and `a` to `z` ([Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash)) conversion, reversing the letters.

This is my code:

```
def answer(s):
    a_z = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
    z_a = sorted(a_z, reverse=True)
    list(s) #trasform the input to list
    s = [s.replace(z_a[i],a_z[i]) for i in range(26)]
    return s
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to take off the for there and print every operation he does, but it`s still not really clear.

Comment: Do you mean you want `abc` to be turned into `zyx`, for instance? Please show desired input/output examples.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt super clear.

Input  "c mvevi, vevi nziph gsv hklg."
Output "x never, ever marks the spot."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = [s.replace(z_a[i],a_z[i]) for i in range(26)]
```

Here, you create a list of 26 strings, each of them being `s` with a letter modified. You don't execute the replacements sequentially, applying each replacement to the result of the last replacement. You're applying all replacements to the original string and keeping the result of all replacements.

You could use a loop and make sure the replacement operations are serialized, but you'll fall into another issue: during the first iteration, `a` would be replaced by `z`, but then during the last one, `z` would be replaced by `a`.

`azb` -> `zzb` -> `zzy` -> ... -> `zzb` -> `aab`

I guess the only solution to this is to loop on the characters of the input string, not on the letters in the alphabet.

From where you are, you can create a conversion dictionary:

```
conv = dict(zip(a_z, z_a))
```

that associates `a` with `z` and so on...

Then you can use a list comprehension to get the translation of each character:

```
result_as_chars = (conv[char] for char in s)
```

then to get a string, join those characters:

```
return ''.join(result_as_chars)
```

Complete function:

```
def answer(s):
    a_z = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
    z_a = sorted(a_z, reverse=True)
    conv_table = dict(zip(a_z, z_a))
    result_as_chars = (conv_table[char] for char in s)
    return ''.join(result_as_chars)
```

I hope this answer helps clarifying things for you. Don't consider this production quality code, though. I'm not sure this algorithm is the best and this implementation is by no means optimized.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats where i was mentally stuck ATM and i was looking for a way out.

I`ll try to follow your suggestions, thanks for explaining to me that particular line, because i wasn`t fully getting it

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm kinda new to python as well but I can help!

First I'll just point out that in python, `list(s)` won't do anything unless it's assigned to a variable. So in my function, you'll see `s = list(s)` , which reassigned s to a list of the string it once was. I also use a dictionary instead of lists for mapping characters. I use your code but create a dictionary where each name has a value that is equal to what Atbash would convert it to. e.g: `mapped['a'] = z`. Hopefully this is making sense. Anyways, here's how I would do it, but I'm sure there are many ways to create this function and mine may not be the best.

```
def cipher(s):
    a_z = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
    z_a = sorted(a_z, reverse=True)
    mapped = dict(zip(a_z, z_a))
    s = list(s)
    for i, val in enumerate(s):
        s[i] = mapped[val]
return ''.join(s)

print cipher('test')
```

Comment: No need to "cast" the string into a list anyway, just drop that `s = list(s)` line. You can iterate on the string.

Comment: I`ll test it on my compiler and i`ll study the whole thing, thanks for the help guys!